# JSON text not autosizing in textview (uniformly in horizontal and vertical direction)

Tags: java, android

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to fetch text from a JSON file uploaded in my Firebase database, but when the text lines are fetched, they aren't auto-sized (wrt x and y-axis), although I used autoSizeTextType = uniform along with added parameters. Blank spaces are still present on the right side (as one can see from the snapshots). I've used 3rd party Gradle dependencies, but, they also don't work out well. So, pls help me out and tell me solution based on my code.

Activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CourseDetail">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="#262628"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_course"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:title="Course Name"
                app:titleTextColor="#ffffff" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="1dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:padding="12dp"
                        android:text="DESCRIPTION"
                        android:textColor="#262628"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="1dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/course_description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
                    android:text="Description "
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="15sp"
                    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
                    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="1dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:padding="12dp"
                        android:text="DEGREE INFROMATION"
                        android:textColor="#262628"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="1dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/degree_information"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="1dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:padding="12dp"
                        android:text="JOB SCOPE"
                        android:textColor="#262628"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="1dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/job_scope"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Activity.java

```
package com.example.shubhojit.careersafter10th;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.shubhojit.careersafter10th.Model.Courses_After10th;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;


public class CourseDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView course_description,deg_info,job_scope;
    ImageView courseImage;
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;

    String courseId="";

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference coursedetail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_course_detail);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        coursedetail = database.getReference("Courses_After10th");

        course_description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.course_description);
        deg_info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.degree_information);
        job_scope = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.job_scope);
        courseImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_course);

        collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.ExpandedAppbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppbar);

        if(getIntent() != null)
            courseId = getIntent().getStringExtra("CourseId");
        if(!courseId.isEmpty())
        {
            getDetailCourse(courseId);
        }
    }

    private void getDetailCourse(String courseId) {
        coursedetail.child(courseId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Courses_After10th course = dataSnapshot.getValue(Courses_After10th.class);

                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(course.getImage()).into(courseImage);
                collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(course.getName());
                deg_info.setText(course.getDegree_Information());
                job_scope.setText(course.getJob_Scope());

                course_description.setSingleLine(false);

                course_description.setText(course.getDescription());
                course_description.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TextView` does not provide Justify kinda alignment available in Word kinda tools.

To Justify text, instead use `WebView` with HTML content. Convert your text into HTML tags with proper alignment and styling. And then load the content in WebView as HTML.